# Selecting 2 columns from a MySQL db with join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

**Teams**

```
+------+--------------+--------------+
| id   |  team_name   |  team_code   |
+------+--------------+--------------+
|  1   |  Wales       | WAL          |
|  2   |  England     | ENG          |
|  3   |  New Zealand | NZL          |
+------+--------------+--------------+
```

**Matches**

```
+------+-----------+-----------+
| id   |  team_a   |  team_b   |
+------+-----------+-----------+
|  1   |  WAL      | ENG       |
|  2   |  ENG      | NZL       |
|  3   |  WAL      | NZL       |
+------+-----------+-----------+
```

I know how a join works, but I can't get my head around how I can query to the database by `Matched.id` to get the team name for BOTH teams from the `Teams` database. Let me explain better

- For each match I need to determine the team names
- I will query by `Matches.id`
- So for Match: 1 I'll need to select 'Wales' and 'England'

Hope I've explained my problem clearly enough, but If I haven't please feel free to ask more questions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The database structure seems to be "off" to me.

You should have both `team_a` and `team_b` as *foreign keys* to the `Teams` table primary key.

You can then join on the IDs (twice) to get the full names.

**Matches**:

```
+------+-----------+-----------+
| id   |  team_a   |  team_b   |
+------+-----------+-----------+
|  1   |  1        | 2         |
|  2   |  2        | 3         |
|  3   |  1        | 3         |
+------+-----------+-----------+

SELECT T1.team_name, T2.team_name
FROM Matches M
  INNER JOIN Teams T1
    ON M.team_a = T1.id
  INNER JOIN Teams T2
    ON M.team_b = T2.id
WHERE M.id = 1
```

Comment: +1. You shouldn't be storing the `team_code` on Matches, you should be `Foreign Key`ing to the Team table.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a code as a key - so long as it's unique

Comment: @podiluska - Then why have an ID field? And two `INT` fields will be much smaller than 2 `CHAR(3)` fields in the DB (more efficient memory and processing wise).

Comment: @Oded Yes your design is better although the OP's is not wrong. But the db design is not the point of the question and in my opinion you should not have changed the design to answer.

Comment: @Clodoaldo - The point of answering is to give the best possible answer. That may including educating and, if one deems so, change the design in order to give such an answer. For example - if someone asks about concatenating SQL - would you not first suggest to use parameters instead?

Comment: this is great. I'm always up for learning, so I've changed the design. One thing you've missed from my question is I need to be able to select WHERE `matches.id = 1` for example @Oded

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select
    matches.*, 
    teamA.team_name as TeamA_Name, 
    teamB.team_name as TeamB_Name
from matches
   inner join teams teamA on matches.team_a = TeamA.team_code
   inner join teams teamB on matches.team_b = TeamB.team_code
where 
   matches.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    m.id, 
    t1.team_name, 
    t2.team_name
from 
    Matches m
    inner join Teams t1 on m.team_a = t1.team_code
    inner join Teams t2 on m.team_b = t2.team_code
```